# "Root file system not defined. Please correct this from partitioning menu" Ubuntu 14.04 installation problem in pre-installed win 8 laptop

Tags: 14.04

I am not exactly new to Linux, but I am facing problems trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Dell Inspiron 14z pre-installed Windows 8 with Secure Boot nand UEFI mode. **I have followed all the prescribed steps of your post regarding Ubuntu installation one of this forum's post [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) **. 
I am able to boot to LiveUSB mode via UEFI mode. But when going through the installation process, partitions don't appear at all on the 4th slide of the install process. So I just press "Install" just to see what happens. There is a pop-up window which says "No root file system defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu." 
I have created three partitions on Windows 8 of which one is entirely free(100 GB) and formatted and ready to be installed on.
Please help me resolve this issue.
Thanks and cheers

Comment: Create a separate ext4 partition and install Ubuntu on it. For  this "No root file system defined", you have to select the mountpoint(`/`) from the dropdown list.

Comment: @AvinashRaj When you say create an ext4 partitio do you mean in Ubuntu because i tried accessing the drives(partitions) from the "Try without Install mode" and I was denied permission. If you mean creating an ext4 partition from Windows, I havent found any way to do that. Request plz guide me with more details. 
Also the drop down list shows only "/dev/sda" and nothing else and the rest of the buttons are unclickable. I tried mounting the partitions even that didnt work.

Comment: Yes, I mean creating an ext4 partition through gparted on clicking try Ubuntu option on startup. Please upload the screenshot of gparted to imgur.com and post back the uploaded link here.

Comment: Thank u for your help. I did not know about Gparted until now. I figured out stuff related to partition allocating w.r.t to my HDD. I have successfully installed Ubuntu :)
Should (or can) I turn ON Secure Boot and Fast Start-Up for Windows 8 (as it seems horribly slower)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is:

- create an ext4 partition (huge space)
- select mounting point (`/`) and set as primary drive
- create a swap partition
- and set it as logical
- create bios reserved partition

  ...and it's running... :)

Answer (score 2):

In windows go to system management --> disk management, select the drive you have windows 8 on , then right click shrink and make space for Ubuntu from the menu (more than 10gb).

See here http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/repartition-hard-disk#1TC=windows-7

Shut-down then boot into the Ubuntu live.

when you get to installation type say "something else".

Then create a ext4 partition in the free space you made in windows and set it to "/" and "format"

you should also partition off some space (same as the amount of ram you have, or more if you want hibernation) and set this as "swap"

Then set the 100mb "UEFI" partition (if you have one) to boot but don't format it.

Click next and it should continue installation.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a few months old now but incase anyone is interested I ran into the same issue when trying to install Linux Mint on my Dell XPS 14. The solution I found was to load the Linux LiveCD/usb and enter "sudo apt-get remove dmraid" in the terminal. After that you should be able to see all of the partitions on the installation page and proceed with the installation as per normal.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I read from Marian, which helped me out! But I didnt do exactly. Scroll till you pass the quote for my steps.

"The solution is:

create an ext4 partition (huge space)
select mounting point (/) and set as primary drive
create a swap partition
and set it as logical
create bios reserved partition

...and it's running... :)"

1. Click on the new partition you created
2. click on the + or - since till you see primary, logical, mounting point so on all in one window frame
3. Do what Marian told you to do "create an ext4 partition (huge space)
   select mounting point (/) and set as primary drive"
4. Then click next or something to create a new partition.
5. Select the new partion you wish to install
6. Click install

Hopefully it'll work for you too!

Answer (score 0):

**its very simple just choose the 
Step1: "try ubuntu" .
Step2: "Open the Terminal".
Step3: "wipefs -a /dev/sdX"
Step4: "reboot"
Step5: "Able to install Now"
Thanks**