# Ubuntu installer no partition type option

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows, windows-8

Today I decided to install ubuntu (12.04 lts because I had the dvd already) alongside my windows 8.1

In every tutorial I've seen so far, when the part of creating a new partition comes, I should have this:

check image: http://leekaelin.co.uk/downloads/TechSpot/Linux_Guides/Ubuntu_11_10/Ubuntu_11_10_Capture3e.JPG

However, what it shows up is only this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qMfQ.png

Where is the "type for the new partition" option? I've searched already and I didn't find a single topic about this. Am I the only one with this problem? What's happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It does not matter. Just select "/" for mount option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary/logical types are the notions related to the old [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#Disk_partitioning) partitions. 
 Windows 8 uses [GPT](http://www.maketecheasier.com/differences-between-mbr-and-gpt/), so no need to worry about it.

Comment: Actually, there's [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1330021) in the installer that causes it to display a primary/logical option on GPT disks.

Comment: I followed your advice of not worrying, and it's working. Thanks, I was just worried i wouldn't be able to boot if the partition wasn't primary, as I'm pretty newb with this things. :)

Answer (score 1):

Boot in "Try Ubuntu without Install" mode. Search for and open GParted Partition Editor and create the desired partition. For creating desired partitions. This answer would help  ["Root file system not defined. Please correct this from partitioning menu" Ubuntu 14.04 installation problem in pre-installed win 8 laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456743/root-file-system-not-defined-please-correct-this-from-partitioning-menu-ubunt)

Then go ahead with installation and you will find required partitions as you expected.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, although I didn't follow your instructions as I'm too newbie for that. It's working already anyway

Comment: lol thats fine...... I am no expert.... had a similar problem......

Answer (score 0):

Your screen shot mostly obscures the partition table list, but it's clear that you've already got at least partitions 2, 3, and 4, and probably partition 1. On an MBR disk, that means that you either can't create more partitions (if they're all primary) or that you'll be able to create nothing but logical partitions (if one of the existing partitions is an extended partition). My suspicion is that this is the cause of the issue. If so, it's not a problem. Linux can install just fine in logical partitions, so unless you run into another problem (say, if you can't create a partition that's large enough for your needs), you should just ignore this issue.

More broadly, keep in mind that installation guides are necessarily written with reference to a limited range of computers. Screen shots, in particular, come from a *single* computer, and so may reflect details of that computer that are different from what you'll see. It can be hard to tell sometimes when a difference is important and when it's not, but an awful lot of differences are *not* important.

Comment: I created the partition and I think it was an extended one...not sure what that means but most important, it is working. It's weird though that I don't have grub2 installed, I have to click "esc" after I start my pc and then go "boot options" and choose ubuntu (where it has dvd boot, pen boot and all those things). I thought grub2 was automatically installed, am I mistaken?