# Trying to install Lubuntu on Windows XP but I need to define a root file system?

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu, acer, windows-xp

I have a big problem with Ubuntu for laptops (Lubuntu), in that I need to define a "Root File System". I am completely new to the Ubuntu family, and thus, I come to you for help. How do I access the Partitioning Menu on my computer? I am running an Acer Aspire One, Model number KAV60, with, currently, Windows XP SP3, and Lubuntu 14.10. If further information is needed, I'd be happy to give it, as long as this can get fixed.

Comment: I have also seen an old post here on AU, and that was this: [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/456743/root-file-system-not-defined-please-correct-this-from-partitioning-menu-ubunt)

Comment: what do you mean by install Lubuntu on windows XP? do you mean to dual boot or to install it as an app with wubi?

Comment: @RonnieDroid I meant that as dual-boot. If I can't, do you (or anyone else) have any other ideas as to how to do this?

Comment: posted an answer, take a look. if my answer helps you, please vote-up and mark it as the right answer.

Comment: 1) when you say *with, currently, Windows XP SP3, and Lubuntu 14.10* does that mean you already installed Lubuntu?  If no, have you already reduced the size of the Windows partition by using Windows tools?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Currently, Lubuntu has been installed via Wubi, but it says that there's, one, too many primary partitions, and then two, there isn't one selected. So, therefore, it's not working at all. Look at my comment on RonnieDroid's answer below.

Comment: I think before you can do anything really you need to set up your partitions.  This is something I'm not real smart on, but I know on these MBR disks you can only have 4 primary partitions.  You need at least 2, more likely 3 for your Lubuntu install.  So you are going to first shrink your windows partition using windows tools to make room on the disk. If you then have 4 partitions already after than...that's too hard for me, seek other guidance.  If you have 3, then make an extended partition and put your 2 or 3 Lubuntu partitions in it. Then you can do a something else install; it'll be OK.

Comment: If this is all about wubi, forget all I said.

Comment: Ok, I found disk management, but it's not letting me shrink the partition or anything. Why?

Answer (score 1):

For root file system you have to select (`/`) as your mountpoint. This sets the partition used as the primary drive by the system.

If you still have problems installing Lubuntu, provide us with more information about the errors, so as to help us better understand the problem.

Comment: But how do I select the mountpoint?

Comment: I read all your other comments. You can refer to [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/547016/387996). It is for Ubuntu, but may be applicable in your case also.

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't work, I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @StevenWhite can you please provide screen shots of the error you are facing.

Comment: I'll try, but I can't make any promises.

Comment: @StevenWhite if you are having problem with booting into the usb drive while boot, you can change it in acer one by repetitively pressing F12 at boot and then selecting USB HDD as priority memory. Restart and you should boot into the usb

Comment: I tried that earlier, it only lets me select a one-time boot drive (by that I mean, it'll try to go into it, but I could restart and it'll go into windows again if I don't hit F12 again.). And even though I could select it, it wouldn't boot into it. (I'm just a bookful of problems)

Answer (score 0):

boot into your lubuntu live-usb, and when it asks you ether to install alongside windows or delite windows and only install lubuntu, choose something else.

there create three ext4 partitions,

first size it at least 20gb an mount it as /

second which you gonna mount as home size it to your liking this will contain all your personal files.

3rd size it as double as your RAM and mount it as swap area.

**Note** you can add or remove partitions by the - and + in the bottom of the setup window.

Comment: i have no usb, this is the download from lubuntu's site. plus, i get stuck before any menus show up. first i get the problem that it says there's too many primary partitions, then it says that the root system needs to be defined. this all happens when it gets to it looking at the installation configuration. ideas?

Comment: you have to make a live-USB or CD/DVD  then install in the way i told you.

Comment: And how would I do that?

Comment: @StevenWhite here you go http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: Alright, can you suggest a partitioning software that allows you to do what I need to do? (It has to be completely free)

Comment: it's free http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer/Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.6.1.exe after you make the Live-USB follow the steps i gave in the answer

Comment: Woah wait, how do I boot into the usb? is it auto detected?

Comment: Tried booting into it, either it's not detecting it, or I don't know how

Comment: @StevenWhite first of all you have to go to your BIOS settings and make sure that boot from USB is enabled, or available for you computer, if it's available and you enable it, make it the first boot device, if not you have to use a DVD or CD instead. good luck.

Comment: Ah... that would explain my problem I'm having with the usb not working... It's currently in the 4th (last) spot. I'll change it.